# How to disable the Nautilus dynamic menu when right clicking on the dock icon? (22.04 and above)

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, files

When right-clicking on the Nautilus Files dock icon, it gives a different menu based on if you have a Files window open or not (shown by the image below):

[image]

I would like to have customized right-click menu that displays the same list of shortcuts whether or not a Files window is open. This was simple in 20.04 and below by adding entries to the `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` file located in `/usr/share/applications/` or `/home/user/.local/share/applications`. However, this does not work in 22.04 and above because the dynamic menu will add those shortcuts plus all of the default locations and bookmarks from the Files application.

Is there a way to disable the dynamic menu, or create a static menu for this?

Comment: This is a software design flaw that you will need to file to the developers of the Dock. I do not know whether it is the original Dash to Dock extension or the modifications by Ubuntu ("Ubuntu Dock ") that implement that behavior.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. I'll have to look into the Dash to Dock extension and Ubuntu Dock a little more. Thanks so much for the information!